# How do I union these 3 tables in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables:

**table1:**

```
pk  c1 
-------
1   1
2   1 
3   1
```

table2:

```
   pk   c2 
  ---------
    3   1
    4   1 
    5   1
```

**table3:**

```
   pk   c3 
  ---------
    6   1
    7   1 
    8   1
```

How would I append or union these three tables to look like a this table??

```
    pk  c1  c2 c3
   ---------------
    1   1   0   0
    2   1   0   0
    3   1   0   0
    4   0   1   0 
    5   0   1   0 
    6   0   1   0 
    7   0   0   1
    8   0   0   1 
    9   0   0   1
```

When I use the union statement now SQL Server spits out 2 columns.

```
select * from #table1 
union 
select * from #table2
union
select * from #table3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give 0 values for the columns not in each table:

```
select pk, c1, 0 as c2, 0 as c3
from t1
union all
select pk, 0 as c1, c2, 0 as c3
from t1
union all
select pk, 0 as c1, 0 as c2, c3
from t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `full join` :

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
        COALESCE(t1.pk, t2.pk, t3.pk) AS pk, 
        COALESCE(t1.c1, 0) AS c1,
        COALESCE(t1.c2, 0) AS c2,
        COALESCE(t1.c3, 0) AS c3
 FROM t1 FULL OUTER JOIN 
      t2
      ON t1.pk = t2.pk FULL OUTER JOIN 
      t3
      ON t2.pk = t3.pk;
```

Comment: (1) `full join` requires an `on` clause.  (2) This will return 6 columns rather than 4.

Answer (score 0):

This might work?

```
    select COALESCE(t1.pk,t2.pk,t3.pk) AS pk, 
           COALESCE(t1.c1, 0) AS c1,
           COALESCE(t1.c2, 0) AS c2,
           COALESCE(t1.c3, 0) AS c3
    from t1 
    full 
   outer
    join t2
      on 1 = 2
    full 
   outer
    join t3
      on 1 = 2;
```